# Analyzing spatial pattern in time using ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, spatial-analyst, statistics

I am analyzing a dispersion of unemployement rate at municipality level in Czechia between 2002 and 2016.
I have chosen LISA analysis which identifies high-high and low-low clusters.

Now I would like to identify and measure whether the municipalities (polygons) are in the same clusters for the whole period. Which municipalites were in high-high cluster at the beginning and have changed the position to low-low clusters after years? I would like to identify which municipalites are stable and are stucked in the one cluster and which ones have moved to any other clusters.

Unfortunately, I do not know how to do it. My only idea is to join all LISA results into one shapefile, then export it to the Excel and then try to analyze it there using excel functions like "if". I believe, there must be a better (and statisticaly correct) method in ArcMap...

Sorry for my english and my poor knowledge of GIS.

[image: LISA]
[image: Attribute table]

Answer (score 1):

The Space Time Pattern Mining tools should be able to do this with the Local Outlier Analysis in ArcGIS Pro, if you have that. [Here's the link to ESRI's documentation.](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/space-time-pattern-mining/localoutlieranalysis.htm)